# Is there a way to get elements from Chrome Browser in pure C#, without Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, iframe

In C# I use FindElement to find element:

```
string text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='errorPopup']")).text;
```

Is there a way to perform such action on chrome without Selenium altogether (that means no IJavaScriptExecutor as well)?

Here’s my problem:
I’m working with Selenium on a Chrome page in a certain IFrame in my main thread. 
I need to constantly search for an Error Popup, in a different IFrame which the Driver points to, without (and this is very important), using SwitchTo(), in a different thread.

Is there a way to go outside an IFrame without SwitchTo()?

Comment: Are you wanting elements from a dynamically created page or is it static.  It's very easy to scrape a static page natively on C#.  However if it is using Javascript to build things in the page, you probably will have a bad/impossible time scraping natively.

Comment: might consider Puppeteer: https://www.toptal.com/puppeteer/headless-browser-puppeteer-tutorial

Comment: if you really wanna go from scratch you could embed Chrome/Chromium into your C# application.  You can then register classes with the browser/page.  Another option may be to write a browser plug-in.